# Android: How AirDroid app does work?

Tags: android, wireless

Hello I am going to develop an app like ["AirDroid"](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) on Android Market which connect a device with the PC using wireless communication.

Can anybody explain to me how this app works?
Is Internet required for that or not? and from where that window which display the content of the device in PC, comming from to explore the Device?

Is it Internet required for that or any server manages that?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but are you really asking us to explain an app **you** that **you** want to develop? This is silly! Also your sentences need improvements as it is hard to understand the second paragraph...

Comment: @WarrenFaith : Sorry regarding my language. But in this app we can able to see our Mobile Data in to PC. and the graphics of the PC also fit to screen and good like any other Computer Software. Thats why i thaught that some data might be comming from the internate. So i want to know its whole process if any one know. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @WarrenFaith: i have close the internet and then try. But in that condition also the app is going to work.

Answer (score 14):

AirDroid is server application based on lightweight PAW Server: http://paw-android.fun2code.de/. I think that the used framework is your main question, isn't it?

Another server you might want to try is Jetty: http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/

Have fun ;)

Comment: yes thats near to my question. But still i want another answer. Is there any other server we can use for same ?

Comment: As I already answered: You can use PAW server or Jetty. So far I don't have any other reference for servers running on Android.

Comment: can i use Apache Server as well? Any idea about it?

Answer (score 5):

actually air droid starts a http server on your phone just like apache does on your computer. ALL THE graphic that you see you can actually retrive from the app itself it doesnt uses internet. You can extract that graphic from the app just by using a zip opener to open the .apk file. It mainly uses client side scripting for exmple javascript.

Comment: Do you have anything like same example ?